# Multiple tokens with same name in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm writing a parser to check the validity of another a scripting language. The parsing itself is working as expected, but I'm unable to access some of the results even though I can see the parser has caught them.

```
function = Forward()
arg = function | condition | constant | attribute | variable
args = delimitedList(arg)
function <<= (functor("FUNCTOR") + lparen + Optional(args)("ARGS") + rparen)("FUNCTION")
```

I'm giving it:

```
r = function.parseString('DecryptSymmetric(@dec64, "AES", @empty, @PASSWORD, @empty, "0000000000000000",@empty, "00000000000000000000000000000000")')
```

and the results indicate that it has caught and recognized the `variable` and `constant` fields in the function.

Entering `r.ARGS` into an interactive prompt gives me:

```
   (['@dec64', 'AES', '@empty', '@PASSWORD', '@empty', '0000000000000000', '@empty', '00000000000000000000000000000000'], {'VAR': ['@dec64', '@empty', '@PASSWORD', '@empty', '@empty'], 'STRING': ['AES', '0000000000000000', '00000000000000000000000000000000']})
```

I want to access the `VAR` portion to validate that the variables have been declared (this part doesn't exist yet)

However, if I access the `r.ARGS.VAR` attribute, I just get the last element in the list.

Functions like `r.asList()` or `r.asDict()` have the same results; I only get the last element in `VAR` or `STRING`.

Strangely, the `r.asXML()` function does give me the output I want (with each variable or string in its own element) but that solution seems too hacky. Digging into the code for pyparsing I see that all three functions use something called `__toklist` to pull out the values, but accessing that myself just gives me an empty string, even if I try it on sub `ParseResults` instances from `r`.

There must be a way to access all the elements in `VAR` since the object is obviously storing and using them, but I cannot find a clean way of doing it. Ideally I would get them all back in a list like:

```
['@dec64', '@empty', '@PASSWORD', '@empty', '@empty']
```

`r.dump()` also displays the fields I want, but in a string which defeats the whole purpose of using the parser.

Comment: Try changing `Optional(args)("ARGS")` to `Group(Optional(args))("ARGS")`

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I get the same thing in that case. I feel like `__toklist` is the key to sorting this out, but I cannot figure out how it works.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. When you define the VAR results name, you must enable the `listAllMatches` flag. If calling `setResultsName` explicitly, this is an optional keyword arg. If using the `expr(name)` shortcut, then append a '*' to the name, `variable = Word('@', alphanums)('VAR*')`. Generally, tho, I would recommend moving these results name definitions further down your parser, since `variable` might be used elsewhere in your grammar. Maybe something like `arg = function | condition | constant | attribute | variable('VAR*')` (and probably similar for the other exprs as well).

Comment: And `function` *must* be `Group`ed, else the internal names will be overwritten.

Comment: Wonderful. It works as expected now. I'm able to get at the variables using `r.ARGS.VAR[i]`. Thanks very much for the help and the module. It's really powerful once you get it working.